# classnotfoundexception when deserialize an object?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am working on windows application in java:

I just test a button that make function login in my system:

My button action performed code:

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if(emp.isSelected()) // get the selected radio button
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        Emp e = new Emp();
        a.setUsername(username.getText().toUpperCase());
        a.setPassword(password.getText().toUpperCase());
        e.login(a);
        this.dispose();
    }

    else if(supp.isSelected())
    {
    }

    else if(admin.isSelected())
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        Admin m = new Admin();
        a.setUsername(username.getText().toUpperCase());
        a.setPassword(password.getText().toUpperCase());
        m.login(a);
        this.dispose();
    }

    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a choice", "Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

The function login code:

```
public class Emp
{

public void login(Account a)
{
    boolean find = false;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\employees.bin"));
        ArrayList<Account> b = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
        Iterator<Account> i = b.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Account ac = i.next();
            if(ac.getUsername().equals(a.getUsername()) && ac.getPassword().equals(a.getPassword()))
            {
                find = true;
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password .. try again !!", "Login Failed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
        if(find)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + a.getUsername(), "Login Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                emp_page e = new emp_page();
                e.setLocation(350, 150);
                e.setSize(400, 490);
                e.setTitle("Products Management");
                e.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Emp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The account class code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable{

private String username;
private String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

I have a problem: i receive error:

```
java.lang.classnotfoundexcetpion:Account
```

and after searching for error reason i found that serialization is the problem of throwing this error because i test this code before in another function that dont use serialization and its worked perfectly.

so my question is: how to fix this error?

**NOTE:** my application is not a client-server application ... so there is no two projects created ... just only one.

Comment: Are those 2 different applications? and does the other app have the class `Account` ?

Comment: Is this a client server application? If that is the case then notice that the package name **must** be equal on both the server and the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916107/readobject-method-throws-classnotfoundexception

Comment: not client-server application.... its java se window application .... class emp and class account are in the same package

Comment: i read the answers of the link posted but really iam not fully understand what to do ..... @Cyclone .... and its not a client-server application. can you please add more details of what to do ??

Comment: @Cyclone i am using netbeans also but its not 2 different projects ... its one only

Comment: Where does the `employees.bin` file comes from? Is it created from the same application?

Comment: @Cyclone After search i found what is the problem ... you was alright sir .... class `Account` was not have the static member `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` ... so i serialize the 'employees.bin' again after adding the static member ... this static member is used for locating class `Account `after it  has been used in serialization... it is not written before in the code so it throws error ... `classnotfoundexception` but now when deserialize object it used to locate the class and code now is running good ... thanks you so much sir ... please write answer again to accept.

Comment: It isn't  used for locating anything. It is used to verify compatibility of the data in the stream with the class that is present when deserializing. Leaving it out does **not** cause `ClassNotFoundException`: it *may* cause `InvalidClassException`. Either you're barking up the wrong tree completely, or you're misreporting the symptoms of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

long discussions about this:

[ClassNotFoundException when deserializing a binary class file's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300076/classnotfoundexception-when-deserializing-a-binary-class-files-contents)

[ClassNotFoundException during Deserialization of a just-serializaed class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874331/classnotfoundexception-during-deserialization-of-a-just-serializaed-class)

[Java SerialIzation: 'ClassNotFoundException' when deserializing an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331987/java-serialization-classnotfoundexception-when-deserializing-an-object)

3 advices :

- be sure to put the private static final long serialVersionUID = XXX;
- be sure to embark your class in your classpath/jar
- force it in code with Account ac=new Account(); // See if problem here

it helps ?

Comment: This barely qualifies as an answer. The only relevant bit is the second bullet point.

Comment: @EJP none of the discussions linked gives a sure answer, only lists symptomes, possible reasons and counter-measures, which I resume. If it exists a sure solution, it would be a big step, no ?